# TFS 2010: Project dashboard reporting service error

Tags: tfs

I have configured TFS 2010, but when I try to load the project dashboard for a team project, it returns a reporting service error so I am not able to see the "Task Burndown (hours)" and " Burn Rate (hours/day)". Other parts of the page are working fine.

The error is as:

> An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) Get Online Help
> Cannot impersonate user for data source 'TfsReportDS'. (rsErrorImpersonatingUser) Get Online Help
> Log on failed. (rsLogonFailed) Get Online Help
> For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got resolution finally....

Go to analysis service.

```
    You will see database named as TFS_Analysis.
    Go to Roles node.
    View properties of "TfsWarehouseDataReader".
    Click on Data Sources.
    Now you will see Tfs_AnalysisDataSource.
    Change access to "Read" and check "Read Definition" box. Now Click OK and You are Done.
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was with SCHEMA CONFLICTS.

First identify which fields are causing schema conflicts, invoke GetWarehouseStatus and observe the XML which fields got conflicted, and in which collection. once you found the filed names then rename the fields with the help of below link.

geekswithblogs.net/Natalia/Default.aspx

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee921480(v=VS.100).aspx

then rebuild your warehouse from tfs admin console, take a back up of old database in sql database and delete it .wait for some time (depends on warehouse time to refresh the cube  or check the GetWarehouseStatus next day and check the xml ). to check this use below link

type  //localhost:8080/tfs/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/WarehouseControlService.asmx?op=GetProcessingStatus

I spend lot of time to resolve this issue, that's why posting the solution here, this may help some one... any queries related schema conflicts and Reporting services feel free to post me... iam not a expert but for sure i can help you out in this issues....

Please use Mark as Answer if my post solved your problem and use Vote As Helpful if a post was useful.